# Mounted NTFS partition with 'reading directory '.': input/output error' exclusively on paths with Umlaut

Tags: ntfs

I had to recover an SSD that wouldn't boot. I created a DiskDump, decrypted via dislocker and the recovery-password. I can read all of the contents, with one exception. All folders that contain an Umlaut ('ä','ö') prompt an error:

'ls: reading directory '.': input/output error'

Usually this would indicate a hardware issue, however, since this is happening in different locations exclusively on paths with Umlaut, I susupect there is another reason.

Thanks for your attention.

Best Regards,

Lammy

Comment: Locale settings? LC_* ?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Suspected: Locale settings plays a role in this. I do not have the knowledge to pinpoint the actual problem though.